# Notation in proof.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just a quick regarding notation. I have to proof the following: $A_i$ is given for each $i \in \{1,2,...,n\} $ with $A_i \subseteq A_j$ whenever $i \leq j $ Show that $\bigcap _{i \in I} A_i = A_1$

While I have got the proof pretty much sorted out, I am unsure how to express the following eloquently:

If $x \in A_1 $ given the nested structure then $ x \in \bigcap A_i$

Comment: $A_1 \subseteq A_j$ for all $j \in \{1,2,...,n\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have expressed this eloquently. If you want to be slightly less informal, you might write this:

> If $x\in A_1$, then because $A_i\subseteq A_j$, and inclusion is transitive we have that $x\in A_i$ for all $i$, and therefore $x\in\bigcap A_i$.

Or perhaps,

> If $x\in A_1$, then because the $A_i$'s are a $\subseteq$-increasing chain, $x\in A_i$ for all $i$, and therefore $x\in\bigcap A_i$.

Comment: Is $ (\forall i \in I) (A_1 \subseteq A_i)$ ok?

Comment: Also works out fine.